# Detecting sound from microphone using Java. Issue with Java Versions

Tags: java, audio, javasound

I'm running this simple code that listens to my microphone and prints out bytes.

Problem:
It listens to the microphone for any changes correctly on
java version "1.6.0_43"

but it doesn't listen to the microphone for any changes correctly on
java version "1.7.0_25"

Code compiles and runs fine on both versions.

Example Output using Java 1.6

- 5172 1
- 5196 2
- 5103 3
- 2859 4
- 2549 5
- 2742 6
- 3112 7
- 5028 8
- 4515 9
- 3856 10
- 5189 11
- 5080 12
- 5165 13
- 4925 14

When it drops down to around 2500 that's when there was sound going into the microphone.

Example Output using Java 1.7

- 5652 1
- 5655 2
- 5699 3
- 6081 4
- 6213 5
- 5972 6
- 5907 7
- 5828 8
- 5931 9
- 6187 10
- 6015 11
- 5949 12
- 6196 13

It no longer detects any noise from the microphone.

```
import java.io.*;
import javax.sound.sampled.*;

public class SpeechDetectionTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream;
        TargetDataLine targetDataLine;
        int cnt;
        boolean stopCapture = false;
        byte tempBuffer[] = new byte[8000];
        int countzero, countdownTimer;  
        short convert[] = new short[tempBuffer.length];
        try {
            byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            stopCapture = false;
            countdownTimer = 0;
            while (!stopCapture) {
                AudioFormat audioFormat = new AudioFormat(8000.0F, 16, 1, true, false);
                DataLine.Info dataLineInfo = new DataLine.Info(TargetDataLine.class, audioFormat);
                targetDataLine = (TargetDataLine) AudioSystem.getLine(dataLineInfo);
                targetDataLine.open(audioFormat);
                targetDataLine.start();
                cnt = targetDataLine.read(tempBuffer, 0, tempBuffer.length);
                byteArrayOutputStream.write(tempBuffer, 0, cnt);
                try {
                    countzero = 0;
                    for (int i = 0; i < tempBuffer.length; i++) {                                   
                        convert[i] = tempBuffer[i];
                        if (convert[i] == 0) {
                            countzero++;
                        }
                    }

                    countdownTimer++;
                    System.out.println(countzero + " " + countdownTimer);

                } catch (StringIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
                    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
                }
                Thread.sleep(0);
                targetDataLine.close();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Any ideas?

Also posted on these forums, but no luck =(

http://www.coderanch.com/t/615528//java/Detecting-sound-microphone-Java-Java#2811088

http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/324610-detecting-sound-from-microphone-using-java-issue-with-java-versions/

Comment: This is not a java version issue. You are incorrectly converting from byte to short.

Comment: you open line with 16-bit format and incorectly use  read bytes to build a 16-bit sample.